# How do I root a Zte Director..can't seem to find much info on how?

Tags: rooting

I have found numerous posts on other Zte phones, but only a few (dead ends) on the Zte Director(n850l). From my research, it seems to be (somewhat) comparable to the Fury, but again, I'm not sure...
I know enough to (possibly) get myself in trouble, and turn it into a paperweight...so, hoping for "easy" to follow directions (if there are any!)
If anyone could help, or even lead me in the right direction, it would be MUCH appreciated!
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. You should take a look at the [Rooting Index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) and the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). These have some common techniques to root if there isn't a specific method for that device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best thing I have found so far for this phone. http://www.how-to-root.club/mp3-0/zte-director-5470.html

Comment: Generally link only answers are not allowed as answers. If the site goes down, or the content is no longer available, then the answer is no longer relevant. Instead you should put the relevant information here and cite the original source. See the help center for [how to reference content](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).